# Login via Xamarin Forms Application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, asp.net-mvc-5, xamarin.android

we have an mvc 5 application with individual user authentication we also have a xamarin forms application. we need to be able to use the same login details thats created on the web application when we log in via the xamarin application we are creating. we have successfully been able to create web api controllers using existing models in the web application and read/write the data in the xamarin application. but the problem is that we are not able to provide the same authentication we have(username and password with role assigned to the user) to the xamarin application. how can we make an api controller that reads from our existing database..please note our application is hosted on azure with a sql database.

basically we want to provide a login to our web application via the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at Adrian Halls book - chapter 2 covers custom authentication which is what you need.

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/

The key points are setting the mobile app to use authentication in the Azure portal but don't set any of the authentication providers (this makes it custom)

You then need to implement your own custom authentication controller to handle the authentication call back like this example taken from Adrian's book;

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AWPBackend.Controllers
{
    [Route(".auth/login/custom")]
    public class CustomAuthController : ApiController
    {
        private MobileServiceContext db;
        private string signingKey, audience, issuer;

        public CustomAuthController()
        {
            db = new MobileServiceContext();
            signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
            var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
            audience = $"https://{website}/";
            issuer = $"https://{website}/";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] User body)
        {
            if (body == null || body.Username == null || body.Password == null ||
                body.Username.Length == 0 || body.Password.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest(); ;
            }

            if (!IsValidUser(body))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, body.Username)
            };

            JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
                claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
            return Ok(new LoginResult()
            {
                AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
                User = new LoginResultUser { UserId = body.Username }
            });
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool IsValidUser(User user)
        {
            return db.Users.Count(u => u.Username.Equals(user.Username) && u.Password.Equals(user.Password)) > 0;
        }
    }

    public class LoginResult
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authenticationToken")]
        public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
        public LoginResultUser User { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginResultUser
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

The actual custom authentication takes place in the IsValidUser function and should link to your existing internal authentication method (do not use the example here, this is for demonstration only)

Custom authentication has to use a client side flow which also meets your requirements.

Comment: Answers that consist of only links are generally discouraged because links can rot or change. Please answer the question in the answer itself.

Comment: Yes I understand that but since the answer is an entire book chapter it seemed rather pointless pasting that here - but thanks for your helpful input.

Comment: I reversed my vote - if it really is a whole chapter, the question should be marked as Too Broad, but generally things can be explained in less.